# cannot add fields to a many2many relation class

Tags: odoo

I created a site class having many2many relation with text class. I'm trying to add some attributes to the many2many relation class.
This is the site class:

```
class site(models.Model):
    _name ='ab.site'
    name = fields.Char('Name')
    text_ids = fields.Many2many('ab.site.text',
                                    'ab_site_text_rel',
                                    'text_id',
                                    'site_id',
                                    'Texts')
```

This is the text class:

```
class text(models.Model):       
    _name = 'ab.text'
     name = fields.Char('Title', required=True)
```

I need to create a non-conformity depending at the same time on the text class and the site class, the user can add a list of non-conformities in the site depending on legal texts, so the non-conformity class is related to both, that's why I'm trying to add it to the relation class.
I create the relation class, I added the applicability field (boolean) and a one2many field (non-conformities):

```
class ab_site_text_rel(models.Model):
    _name = "ab.site.text.rel"
    _rec_name = "site_id"
    site_id = fields.Many2one('ab.site', 'Site', ondelete='cascade')
    text_id = fields.Many2one('ab.site.text', 'Text', ondelete='cascade')
    applicability = fields.Boolean(string='Applicability')
    nonconformity_ids = fields.One2many('ab.nonconformity','ab_site_text_rel','Non-conformities')
```

I got this key error when running the server:

```
File "/home/euromed/git/odoo9/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 200, in setup_models
model._setup_fields(cr, SUPERUSER_ID, partial)
File "/home/euromed/git/odoo9/openerp/api.py", line 250, in wrapper
return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/euromed/git/odoo9/openerp/api.py", line 354, in old_api
result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/euromed/git/odoo9/openerp/models.py", line 3046, in _setup_fields
field.setup_full(self)
File "/home/euromed/git/odoo9/openerp/fields.py", line 495, in setup_full
self._setup_regular_full(model)
File "/home/euromed/git/odoo9/openerp/fields.py", line 1893, in _setup_regular_full
invf = comodel._fields[self.inverse_name]
KeyError: 'ab_site_text_rel'
```

Comment: You can not add more attributes to m2m relational model, it should have only 2 keys, according to this framework. If you want to achieve this then you should define new model and in that model define all the necessary fields and then define this new model with m2m relation.\

Answer (score 2):

**Relational Fields:**

Relational fields are fields with values that refer to other objects. Relationship can be Unidirectoinal or Bi-directional.

In general, there are main three types of relation.

**1. Many2one**

Normal relationship towards to other objects (using a foreign key)

[image]

Invoice lines contains reference of invoice (invoice_id)

```
invoice_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='account.invoice', string='Invoice')
```

**2. One2many**

- Virtual relationship towards multiple objects (inverse of many2one).
- A one2many relational field provides a kind of “container” relation:
  the records on the other side of the  Relation can be seen as
  “contained” in the record on this side.
- In a one-to-many relationship between Table A and Table B the rows in
  Table A are linked to zero, one, or many rows in Table B. This
  relationship allows information to be saved in a table and referenced
  many times in other tables.

[image]

```
invoice_line = fields.One2many(comodel_name='account.invoice.line', inverse_name='invoice_id', string='Invoice Line')
```

**3. Many2many**

- Bi-directional multiple relationship between objects.
- This is the most general kind of relation: a record may be related to any number of records on the other side, and vice-versa.
- In the case of a many-to-many relationship, each row in Products is linked to zero, one or many rows in Taxes and vice versa. Normally, New Table a mapping table is required to map such kind of relationships.
- In this relationship new table is required to store reference of the
  both table.
  [image]

Many2many field definition.

```
taxes_id = fields.Many2many(comodel_name='account.tax', relation='product_taxes_rel', column1='prod_id', column2='tax_id', string='Customer Taxes')
```

========================================================================

Actually in this framework we don't need to care about the relational table of M2M, that will be auto managed. So in your case it's not required. And I am not sure why you have created this class, be specific with your requirements. And try to update question with the target you want to achieve.

**class ab_site_text_rel(models.Model):**

This is not required.